# Is eating soap or bleach dangerous?

Tags: food-safety, cleaning, milk, boiling, chemistry

i was cooking some dessert today which contains milk as a primary ingredient. While cooking I started to notice that powder ingredients weren't dissolving in the milk. After a while under heat they dissolved, but I noticed what looked like soap bubbles. We usually use Fairy Soap for washing kitchen tools and Clorox. Now I'm concerned if we can eat what I've made or if it poisoned. The soap came out of the tool I was using to cook the dessert.

Comment: It sounds like you used a package of some dry powder and dissolved it in milk to make the dessert. Some powders (like starch and flour) can only mix with cold liquids and form clumps in hot liquids. Other powders (like kokoa) can only mix with warm liquids and float on cold liquids. Other again (like gelatine) need some time to soak up the liquid and dissolve. There might be nothing wrong with your dessert, but better have a cautious taste and throw it away if anything seems odd.

Comment: Is this something you've made before so you'd be familiar with how it looks while cooking, or is it a new recipe? If a familiar recipe, did you do anything different or use different ingredients? There are some other possible explanations for what you saw.

Answer (score 2):

Most pure soap is safe to eat in small amounts, but the food won't taste great. Fairy Soap, from [some brief research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5606372/), is safe to ingest in small quantities, but I wouldn't recommend it. Bleach in very small and diluted concentrations won't hurt you, but it's very toxic if larger quantities are ingested, particularly undiluted. It is a very strong base. If you think you put (any) bleach in your food I would throw it away. If you think you put soap in your food, I'd also throw it away. The maxim I live by is: "When in doubt, throw it out."

Answer (score 2):

By the time you could get anywhere near enough soap or bleach in food to be vaguely dangerous, it would be so strong you wouldn't be able to eat a second mouthful.

You can try these tests:-

- Wash a spoon in your regular washing-up bowl before anything else, so it's as clean as clean can be. Don't rinse, just shake it once. Lick it. How strong did that taste? Imagine doing the same with a pan, but afterwards half filling it with water or food as you're cooking it. That concentration would then be further diluted by a thousand-fold.
- Touch your finger lightly to the open top of the Washing-up liquid bottle. Taste.
  Now, that still won't do you any harm, but would you imagine being able to eat anything with that kind of soap concentration in it?

**Don't** repeat the tests for bleach. The smell alone is enough to warn you not to go anywhere near any concentration high enough to be able to still smell it in food.

***Note:*** soap is not the only substance that will form bubbles. Bubbles alone are zero indication of soap contamination.